# Twitter Spark Stream Filtering: Task not serializable exception

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to build a Spark application which will filter Twitter streaming feeds based on the list of words I have. I have around 8000 words in my list (Twitter filtering API supports only max upto 400 words). I want to tokenize each incoming tweet into words and then check whether this word exists in my list or not. If any of the word from tweet is in the list, then I should print the tweet, else reject it.

I have written following code to achieve this (I copy paste the following code a few lines at a time on *spark-shell*, is this the right way to test/run my code?):

```
// excluding imports to keep in concise 
val consumerKey = "" // removed while posting on SOF
val consumerSecret = "" // removed while posting on SOF
val accessToken = "" // removed while posting on SOF
val accessTokenSecret = "" // removed while posting on SOF
val url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Sentiment Analysis")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)


val csvFilterWordsList = sc.textFile("<path to file>/uniq_list_8.0_sorted")
var filterWordsList : Set[String] = Set()
for(filterWords <- csvFilterWordsList.collect()) {
    filterWordsList += filterWords.split(",")(0)
}



// Twitter Streaming
val ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,Seconds(2))

val conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
conf.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
conf.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)
conf.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
conf.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
conf.setStreamBaseURL(url)
conf.setSiteStreamBaseURL(url)

val filter = Array("twitter")

val auth = AuthorizationFactory.getInstance(conf.build())
val tweets : JavaReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status] = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, auth, filter)

object test extends Serializable {
def similarity(tweet : twitter4j.Status, wordsList : Set[String]) : String = {
    val tweetTokenized = tweet.getText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ").split(" ")
    var flag = false
    for(word <- tweetTokenized) {
        if(wordsList.contains(word)) {
            flag = true
        }
    }
    if(flag && tweet.getUser.getLang == "en") {
     return (tweet.getText + "," + tweet.getUser.getLang)
    }
    else {
     return ""
    }
}
}
val statuses = tweets.dstream.map(status => test.similarity(status,filterWordsList))

statuses.print()
ssc.start()
```

But on running this I am getting following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.map(DStream.scala:436)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:64)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:76)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:78)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:84)
    at <init>(<console>:86)
    at .<init>(<console>:90)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
```

But when I just do a simple mapping like
`val statuses = tweets.dstream.map(status => status.getText)`
it works fine.

Can someone please help me on where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm so surprised that my Google search actually yielded a result that helped me on such a specific search. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spark-shell encapsulates the code in anonymous classes to serialize and ship the code to the workers. 
Sometimes it's tricky to know what's being captured  and in which scope. If you're copy/pasting your code in the spark-shell, even the order and amount of lines your are pasting together (with `:paste` for example) will result in different class structures.

A rule of thumbs to avoid serialization issues is to mark `@transient` all the elements you know are not required in the dstream operations. In this specific case, I would add the transient annotation to `conf`,`auth` and `tweets`.

Comment: Along with `conf`, `auth` and `tweets`, I had to make `sparkConf`, `sc`, `ssc` and `statuses` also as transient variables to make this work. Although, I do not completely understand what is happening here. Will look into the details now. Thanks !!

Comment: Try making your test a function val instead of a method: `val similarity: twitter4j.Status => Set[String]) => String =??? ` this should avoid pulling too much of your context into the closure serialization